# Angular (TypeScript): How to scroll to selected element by class

Tags: angular, typescript

Please don't mark this as duplicate, I have searched and searched and couldn't find a solution

So let's say I have a list of orders called "orders"

In my view I present these orders and their details in a sidebar that has vertical scrolling set:

```
<div>

    <div id="main-content">
        Main Content
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">

        <div *ngFor="let order of orders" [ngClass]="{'selected-order': selectedOrder == order}>
           <div>order.orderNumber</div>
           <div>order.orderDetails</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

In my main content I have map that has markers when I click on a marker I'm I want the correct order to be selected and I want the sidebar to scroll and focus on the right order.

This is what I've tried:

```
function selectMarker() {

    //...omitted code

    // scroll to correct marker in sidebar
    var offset = $(".selected-order").offset();
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        scrollTop: offset.top,
        scrollLeft: offset.left
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is not working, it's not selecting the right element.

Is there a pure Typescript/Angular solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `ElementRef` and `scrollIntoView`.

```js
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

...

contructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

function selectMarker() {
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.selected-order').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  function selectMarker() {
        var el = $(".selected-order");
        var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
        var count = el.offset().top - sidebar.offset().top - sidebar.scrollTop();
        if (count < 0) {
            count = el.offset().top - sidebar.offset().top + sidebar.scrollTop();
        }
        sidebar.animate({
            scrollTop: count
        }, 1000);

    }
```

I ignored scrollLeft, but it should be the same- you shuld pay attention to where the scroll is located then take up/down or left/right

goodluck :]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same idea to scroll to an element which is selected on some view.
So I created a directive with a possibility to pass a class name as parameter.

scroll-to-selected.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollToSelected]'
})
export class ScrollToSelectedDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() scrollToClass: string;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains(this.scrollToClass)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
    }
  }
}
```

and the list-item.component.ts itself:

```
<div class="list-item"
     *ngIf="lostItems$ | async as listItem"
     scrollToSelected
     [scrollToClass]="'selected'"
     [class.selected]="listItem.isSelected">
...
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollIntoView` will solve your problem.

```
element.scrollIntoView()
```

> Be careful while using `scrollIntoView`, if you used it without options it may scroll your entire page so don't forget to provide necessary options as below.

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```